# Need assistance regarding adding textfield accessory view in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` which contains `UITextField`, This custom cell has a `xib file` in which I created the `UIView` and add a `IBOutlet` in `cell.m` and in `awakeFromNib` I did this `self.theTextField.inputAccessoryView = accessoryView;`.

When executing the code I am getting `assertion failure in [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"remeTypeListCellId" forIndexPath:indexPath];`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the method:

```
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:
```

Try to use instead:

```
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
```